# Order total amount looks incorrect

Tags: orders

I'm trying to understand how Magento is calculating the total amount for an order when using a coupon discount.

The item purchased is $554.26 without taxes.
The tax is 8.25%.
The coupon discounts 10% from the order.

The settings are Apply Customer Tax after discount, and Apply Discount On Prices excluding tax.

[image: Magento order]
[image: Magento settings]

Shouldn't the total be calculated in this manner:
554.26(subtotal) - 55.42(discount) = $498.84 
$498.98 + 8.25% ($41.17) = $540.15

Maybe I still don't understand exactly how the Apply Customer Tax and Apply Discount On Prices actually work.

Any idea how Magento is doing the calculations ?

Thanks.

PD: I'm using a vanilla install of Magento 1.12.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Magento is calculating:

Tax: 554.26 × 0.0825 = 45.72645.

Subtotal + Tax: 554.26 + 45.72645 = 599.98645.

Total - Discount: 599.98645 - 54.42 = 544.56645

I think if you tweak some settings in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Calculation Settings` and `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order` then you can get it to the computation that you're expecting but the way I have it broken out above is how it's computing based on your current settings.

Comment: Shouldn't it be applying the tax after the discount and not before according to the settings (Apply customer tax after discount)?